# How to run ASP in XAMPP?

Tags: asp-classic, xampp

I have tried installing the asp mod into my xampp, however, I got a Server Error when I am trying to run a asp file.

Anyone can help? Thanks!

or Is there any alternative method for this?

Answer (score -1):

in IIS/Windows are you using the Classic pipeline?
Also lets make sure that it's not the source code that is giving you any errors I don't think it is but just to be on the safe side you can just create a new page name it something like test.asp save it and inside write some code like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test ASP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
strMessage = "Hello World"
Response.Write (strMessage)
%>
</body>
</html>
```

then in your web browser run it and see if you get a message saying Hello World if not then you will need to install classic-asp in IIS.

**Please Note:** Classic ASP in **NOT** installed by default on IIS 7.0 / 7.5 [look here if you need instructions on how to install it.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/562/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis/)

This will solve your problem that you are having with Classic-ASP in Windows/IIS.

Good luck and let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for your method, I have tried what you said, it didn't work well either, I am not sure whether XAMPP is causing this conflict.

Comment: so when you created the test.asp page and tried to run it, it did not show a Hello World message? did you install Classic ASP on IIS?

Comment: Try visiting localhost or 127.0.0.1 and do you see a image that looks like this http://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/up/sshot-2009-08-27-17-54-42.png If you do see this then your installation of IIS was successful but your installation of Classic ASP on the IIS server was not done correctly or the configuration is off, look here just to confirm that the steps your took where something like this: http://www.hkvstore.com/aspmaker/doc/aspprimer.htm if you are running classic-asp on 63-BIT Windows go here http://www.hkvstore.com/aspmaker/doc/aspprimer.htm#64bit

Comment: let me know if you see that screen or not then we will continue, don't give up your almost there!!! :)

Comment: Will try and give you the answer as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

you can only run ASP.NET ([install instructions](http://www.todayinwindows.com/2011/08/how-to-run-asp-net-on-xampp/))

Comment: That is what I have tried, it shows me Server Error, I have tried installing IIS in Windows itself, it also causes some problems too.

Comment: @user1544809 what version of Windows do you have ? for example in Windows 2008 R2 the error 500 - Internal Server Error can and usually does mean that the source code  of your page is causing the error and inorder to see what line/error details you have to make acouple changes see this link http://www.dondraper.com/2011/01/500-internal-server-error-from-iis-7-5-on-windows-2008-r2/ so again let us know what version of Windows/IIS you have, Thanks.